# Azure Data Factory REST API return invalid JSON file with pagination

Tags: azure, api, rest

I'm building a pipeline, which copy a response from a API into a file in my storage account. There is also an element of pagination. However, that works like a charm and i get all my data from all the pages.

My result is something like this:

```
 {"data": {
  "id": "Something",
  "value": "Some other thing"
}}
```

The problem, is that the copy function just appends the response to the file and thereby making it invalid JSON, which is a big problem further down the line. The final output would look like:

```
{"data": {
  "id": "22222",
  "value": "Some other thing"
}}
{"data": {
  "id": "33333",
  "value": "Some other thing"
}}
```

I have tried everything I could think of and google my way to, but nothing changes how the data is appended to the file and i'm stuck with an invalid JSON file :(

As a backup plan, i'll just make a loop and create a JSON file for each PAGE. But that seems a bit janky and really slow

Anyone got an idea or have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy data from Rest API to blob storage it will copy data in the form of `set of objects` by default.

Example:

```json
sample data
{ "time": "2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z", "callingimsi": "466920403025604"}

sink data
{"time":"2015-04-29T07:12:20.9100000Z","callingimsi":"466920403025604"}
{"time":"2015-04-29T07:13:21.0220000Z","callingimsi":"466922202613463"}
{"time":"2015-04-29T07:13:21.4370000Z","callingimsi":"466923101048691"}
```

This is the invalid format of Json.

To work around this, select file pattern in sink activity setting as  `Array of objects` this will return array of all objects.
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pratik Lab, 
Thank you for your response, i would image so aswell, but 'Set of objects' and 'Array of objects' gives the same result, which isn't a array. 

{"data": {
  "id": "22222",
  "value": "Some other thing"
}}
{"data": {
  "id": "33333",
  "value": "Some other thing"
}}

Any idea why or what to look for?

Comment: Ok found the "bug", i used 'debug' -> didn't work but with 'Trigger now' it works like a charm.

Thanks alot again!